# Blocking a user in Asp.Net identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

There was such a problem, I need to block the user. 
I found the function: "SetLockoutEndDate" and "SetLockoutEnabled". But not one of them, I can not help. The first function works well, it blocks, but only when the user logs out and stopped. I need to lock the user after the message appears. How can we realize the lock member in asp.net identity 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should, preferably, implement your own logic to prevent the user from logging in. You can implement a "Locked" or "Disabled" property in the `ApplicationUser` entity. That will give you more control over the logic.

As to how to prevent the user from continuing to use the application right after he's "blocked", you can sign him out using the `AuthenticationManager` class, like this:

```
var autheticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
autheticationManager.SignOut();
```

When the user tries to log in again, your logic should prevent it.

Alternatively, you can use the `SetLockoutEndDate` method that you mentioned, but that will lock the user only until until the specified "date time offset" is reached. `SetLockoutEnabled` will not lock out the user, but enable the lockout itself. If you opt for using the built in lockout, you can still sign out the user as I mentioned and that will prevent him/her from loggin in.

**EDIT**

As you mentioned in the comments, you are having trouble implementing global filters that will prevent unauthorized users to access your application.

First thing you need to do is to implement an `IAuthorizationFilter` or simply create a class that derives from `AuthorizeAttribute`. The advantage of using the latter is that you can still use it as an attribute.

For more info, please refer to: [how to create custom authorize filter in asp.net mvc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241022/how-to-create-custom-authorize-filter-in-asp-net-mvc3)

After, you need to register your filter globally so you don't have to manually implement it in every single action. To do so, in your `global.asax` file, add this to your `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new YourFilter());
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ready-made solution to identity not? 
I thought that most will need to build upon. But wanted to make sure.

Comment: SetLockoutEnabled - this field is not affect anything. Field of the database is always true. Strange that on the internet I found not a ready-made solution, how to get the user exit.

Comment: The only thing that I found: http://www.byteblocks.com/Post/AspNet-Identity-Lock-and-Unlock-User-Accounts. But here the problem I mentioned in the question. Sorry for my English.

Comment: As for SetLockoutEnabled, probably the value in the database is "always" true because it's the default value (I'm not sure). Probably setting it to false using SetLockoutEnabled will cause the DB field to go false.

Comment: As for forcing the user to imediately exit, can't you just sign the user out?

Comment: I have authorization occurs through social networks, if you're asking. I see really only solution is a change in the Authorize attribute.

Comment: When I block a user. He could easily use the functionality. But after exiting and re-attempt to enter, he receives notification. Can you help me? Create MVC and see?

Comment: Im sorry.. I didn't quite understand what you meant by "change the Authorize attribute"

Comment: I'm talking about an attribute that checks the user is logged in or not. Anyone who puts in front of a function or class. I think it can be changed and add handler.

Comment: Oh yes.. if you are not doing it yet, all your private content should be "behind the wall" of the Authorize attribute. If most of your controllers are private. You should register "AuthorizeAttribute" as a global filter or implement your own "IAuthorizationFilter".

Comment: Thank you! Can you give an example of how you can without changing the "[Authorize]" to complement it. I just have a lot of code that uses it "[Authorize]". I would like everything to be in harmony :)

Comment: I edited the question to help you. I'm leaving now. If you found that helpful, don't forget to upvote and/or marking as answer. Thank you.